# Formula for finding the number of times a value appears in a string of numbers

Tags: excel, numbers, excel-formula, formula

I've recently been given a string of numbers.

"3131111233021131231221112223112232223313332221033333131333111233111132221311222113311223232112122321"

My job is to find out how many times a certain value (number) appears in this string. This also includes variations of that value. For instance, in the example "3131111233":

"3" - Appears twice. "1" - Appears once. "1111" - Appears once. "2" - Appears once "33" - Appears once.

Apologies if I am not clear enough but this is the general idea.

So my questions are:
1. Are there any Excel formulas to help with this?
2. Is Excel the appropriate program? Or are there better programs out there?

Aaron

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the following formula:

```
=SUM(LEN(<range>)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(<range>;"text";"")))/LEN("text")
```

Where range is the cell containing the source text and text is what you want to find.
For example if you want to find the value 3 in the cell a1 the code will be:

```
=SUM(LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1;3;"")))/LEN("3")
```

and will return 4.

Basically it replaces what you want to find with empty and then check the differences in the text lenght, the result is how many times the string was replaced (it also count the string length in the `LEN("3")` piece of code)